# "The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed" although they are installed

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I'm trying to deploy WPF app into remote server (Win2003) using clickOnce. I have installed FrontPage Server extensions (the FPSE said that installation was successfull). I have also created website in IIS 7 and extended it with FPSE. However after I click "Publish' option in VS2010, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error 3 Failed to copy file
'E:\Development\Hospital\trunk\GuiMain\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Fdj.Eurp.GuiMain_1_0_0_2\AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll.deploy' 
to 'http://192.168.1.101:8080/Application Files/Fdj.Eurp.GuiMain_1_0_0_2/AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll.deploy'. 
Unable to add 'Application Files/Fdj.Eurp.GuiMain_1_0_0_2/AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll.deploy' to the Web site.  
The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed.
1    1    GuiMain (UI\GuiMain)
```

What may be wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you read the following articles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the wwwrot directory do you see folders like "_vti_bin" "_vti_cnf" "_vti_log" ... ? 
If yes, then FPSE are installed. 
If no, then they need to be activated for the site:
click on the "Configure Server Extensions 2002" in the IIS MCC console

(if you're using Microsoft SharePoint may be this is helps you too http://www.visualwin.com/FPSE/ )